# Visual Studio / VB.Net 2008 IntelliSense Odd Behavior

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I am primarily a C# developer; however, I am currently working on a project for a client who preferred VB.net.  I have managed to switch over fairly well, with one frustrating exception.  When editing a C# file in Visual Studio pressing enter will select an item out of the IntelliSense window and keep the cursor at the end of the selected statement.

However, when editing a VB file, pressing enter selects the item out the IntelliSense popup AND moves the cursor to the next line.  I realize that this is a small thing, but it drives me crazy, because it makes it really hard to switch between C# and VB projects.

I have searched for everything I can think of in Google and found nothing.  Does anyone know of a way to change the IntelliSense selection behavior?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't check right now, but I think SPACE (or was it TAB?) works the same for C# and VB, so it might be worth switching the habit to something portable between VB and C#.

Comment: Hit Tab instead of Enter and it will stay on the same line.

Comment: I moved from VB to C# and continued to use `tab` to select items from IntelliSense!!!

Comment: The question is not about tab or space but how to modify the behaviour of the ENTER key.

Comment: The tab and/or space keys are definitely an option, but it would be nice if I could modify the existing behavior to accommodate my existing habit. :)

Comment: I'd suggest Ctrl-Space but as @Martin rightly pointed out the question is about Enter key behaviour in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just can't be done with VB.NET for now, [according to this thread from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vbide/thread/d820e657-5540-473b-b7f6-9e6fd066a5b9).

One reader there suggested and [open source IDE called SharpDevelop](http://sharpdevelop.net/opensource/sd/) to get C# behaviors on VB.NET code.

Comment: I was hoping for better news, but at least now I know for sure.  I will see if I can switch to using tab.  Thanks for the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the CTRL+SPACEBAR to use Intellisense of popup. This will effect of your Intellisense in between VB and C#.